# Route to different databases depending on the group of users in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a project with Django rest framework as backend and Vue as frontend and everything works well.

Now, I have to extend my project. I want to bring the same product, but to a new group of users, who will have **0 interaction with the first group of users**. No data will be shared among the two groups of users. Like if I created a copy of my backend with a new database and directed the new group of users to this new backend.

So, I am looking for a solution not to have to build another backend for each new independent group of users (which is obviously less than ideal).

I could create permissions where users could only access data about their own group and change every querysets. But I think it is not optimal to keep everyone on the same table as the number of groups of users will grow.

I guess the ideal would be to have 1 database per group of users, 1 backend in total, and to route users to their own group specified by the api call they make with a */groupID/rest-of-endpoint*

Is that possible in Django ? Do you see any solution ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Implementing a solution for that requires a fair bit of code.  Is there something in particular you're having trouble with or can you show us a problem area in your code?

Comment: Thank you @j3py ! Actually it was more a design question : toward what direction should I go ? Would you go toward only 1 database and then manage the difference between user groups using custom permissions, querysets, and django groups ? Or would you go multiple databases with custom precise router ? Or do you have another trick I don't know about ?
It's more a high level question than a precise code request. Sorry if SO is not meant for that kind of question